# App.config Database Settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, app-config

I am setting up a C# Console Application. I am struggling getting the Database connections set up correctly.

Here is my App.Config :

```
<add name="ExportVcallData.Properties.Settings.Setting"
     connectionString="Data Source=XXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXX;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXX"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Here is my Connection string

```
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection();
con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager  
  .ConnectionStrings["ExportVcallData.Properties.Settings.Setting"]
  .ConnectionString;
```

I get:

> Additional information: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
>   Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Any Ideas?

Comment: I think I missed the App.Config:                                                                <add name="ExportVcallData.Properties.Settings.Setting" connectionString="Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Your provider name is System.Data.SqlClient, you're using a SQL Server connection string, and an OdbcConnection. Do you actually intend to use ODBC? If not, use [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I think @mason is on the right track, you are probably trying to connect to a sql server database based on the content of your connection string. See the marked duplicate for how to create a `SqlConnection` instance. If you really do want an ODBC connection see the other 2 related questions in the duplicate links.

Comment: And if you want more help you need to provide the details of where you are stuck and include what it is you are actually trying to connect to.

Comment: Thanks!  Very silly error...you all were a big help